# JButton with both icon (on top) and text (on bottom) aligned to the left

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jbutton

I would like to have a JButton with both icon (on top) and text (on bottom) aligned to the left. The Button can be resized by the user and both should always remain aligned to the left, like this:

[image]

I have tried this

```
// Text alignment
comp.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
// text position
comp.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
//set icon alignment?!
comp.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

but this is my result (The icon always remains centred in relation to the text!):

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use the `<br>` tag to split the `JButton` text onto multiple lines along with the `<html>` tags.
- Another common way is to place multiple `JLabel`s on a `JButton` by setting the `LayoutManager`.

[image: screenshot]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class ButtonTextAlignmentTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
    String text = "The text aligned to the left";

    String html = String.format("<html><img src='%s'/><br/>Html: %s", makeIconUrl(icon), text);
    JButton button1 = new JButton(html);

    JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(null, icon, SwingConstants.LEADING);
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Layout: " + text);
    JButton button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    button2.add(iconLabel);
    button2.add(textLabel);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(button1);
    p.add(button2);
    return p;
  }

  private static String makeIconUrl(Icon icon) { // Create a dummy URL for testing
    try {
      File file = File.createTempFile("dummy", ".png");
      file.deleteOnExit();
      BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
      icon.paintIcon(null, g2, 0, 0);
      g2.dispose();
      ImageIO.write(bi, "png", file);
      return file.toURI().toURL().toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      return "";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ButtonTextAlignmentTest().makeUI());
      frame.setSize(320, 240);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @aterai! The option 2 with layout was exactly what I needed. I did not think the solution was too easy.